# Whole amend diff with pre-commit hook

Tags: git, githooks

I am working on a pre-commit trigger. This trigger should analyze the whole diff.
For that I do:

```
git diff-index --cached HEAD | myprogram
```

Now I noticed, that this fails for amending (e.g. with git gui). In this scenario, the diff between index and HEAD can be empty (when no changes were done) or only partial. This is because HEAD has not been reset. Probably in this scenario I would need to do HEAD - 1, which seems hacky (and I have not yet found a way to distinguish amend).

Is there a general way to handle this properly?

Comment: The short answer is "no". Probably the pre-commit hook should get such information, but it doesn't. There are even more hacky methods using process tree to find the `git commit` command and examine its arguments...

Comment: Thanks. I think I will give the process tree approach a go.